# Pandas Transforming Time Series 15 minutes Data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, python-datetime

I have a time series data with price values taken at every 15 minutes time block. I want to transform the data in which each time block becomes a column, and we get one row of a particular date.
Example, a data frame containing 2 columns- ['Date-Time', 'Price'] results into a dataframe of 1+96 columns- ['Date'] and 96 columns of each time block.

Here is the code I have written for transforming the Hours into columns- which given 24 columns of hours. How do I tranform it 15 minutes wise into 96 columns-

```
def transform_to_hour_cols(series):
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    start = series.index.min()
    end = series.index.max()
    
    df['year'] = series.index.year
    df['month'] = series.index.month
    df['day'] = series.index.day
    df['hours'] = series.index.hour
    df['loads'] = series.values
  
    
    df = df.set_index(['year', 'month', 'day', 'hours'], append=True).unstack()
    df = df.groupby(['year', 'month', 'day']).sum()
    
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.drop(['year', 'month', 'day'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    date_list = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(date_list, name='date')
    
    return df

price = transform_to_hour_cols(df['Price'])
price.head()
```

Here is the sample Data Frame-

[image]

Comment: You can use `Series.dt.minute` to get the minute wise distribution. Since your data only has a 15 min window, it will automatically adjust the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can create a `date` and `time` column with `dt.date` and `dt.time`.
2. Then, send `time` to columns. In order to do this, first, you have to put `date` and `time` on the index with `.set_index()`. Then, use `.unstack(1)` to move `time` to columns. The `1` in `unstack()` means you are passing the second index column in the multiindex you just created. If you had passed `0`, then you would have sent `date` to the columns.
3. Finally, clean up the column multi-index with `.reset_index(level=0)`

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2020-04-01 00:00:00', '2020-04-01 00:15:00',
                             '2020-04-01 00:30:00', '2020-04-01 00:45:00', '2020-04-01 01:00:00'],
                   'mcp' : [2399.21, 2499.07, 2448.89, 2399.80, 2199.89]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date
df = df.set_index(['date', 'time']).unstack(1).reset_index(level=0)
df
Out[1]: 
           date      mcp                                    
time            00:00:00 00:15:00 00:30:00 00:45:00 01:00:00
0    2020-04-01  2399.21  2499.07  2448.89   2399.8  2199.89
```

With the sample data you have provided, I'm assuming you have already successfully grouped into 15-minute intervals by date row-wise, so this just helps you get the 15-minute intervals into columns.